# ubuntu won't boot error

Tags: boot, fsck

### What I think caused the error

I have installed ubuntu on an external SSD Drive, I was using it for several days,  But when I booted it up it just gave me this error :

```
busybox v1.30.1 built-in shell ash ubuntu
```

Somehow, I managed to fix it by

```
*fsck /dev/sda1 -y*
```

and then

```
sudo reboot
```

and then restart my laptop and it's done.

### Problem

later my windows 10 that I had installed on the internal SSD won't boot!!

I somehow managed to reinstall windows 10 again without any issues,

But I want to know that why solving this error ruined my windows?

How to fix it if the problem occurs in future, What can be the possible cause for this?

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, it depends on the capacity of your internal SSD. If it is greater than 512 GB, you can install Windows and Ubuntu basic packages and usable in general sense. If it is smaller than it, you have to think and avoid big data and applications or use an external drive to store them. Search 'dual boot' here, you get what you want.

Comment: Edit your question and add complete details and context. You say you know how to fix it.  How exactly have you been doing that?  You say your actions damaged your Windows installation.  How exactly did that happen?  Please include specific reproducible details so we can understand what is going on.